# React component in Switch not loading automatically on page load(React beginner)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm a React beginner and I've tried to build my homepage based on this logic(not my code): https://github.com/vumbula/vumbula-react/tree/master/chapter5/Link-example/src

---

This is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './components/App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root'));
```

And this is my App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';
import Film from './Film.js';
import TV from './TV.js';
import me from '../images/me-cropped.png'
import film from '../images/film.png'
import tv from '../images/tv.png'


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Link to="/">
          <div className="banner">
            <div className="banner-content">
              My favs
              <img src={me} alt="me" height="140px" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Link>
        <div className="mainpage">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/film" component={Films} />
            <Route exact path="/tv" component={TVseries} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export const Home = () => (
    <div className="mainpage-content">
      <div className="text-row">
        <a className="film-text">
          Film
        </a>
        <a className="tv-text">
          TV
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="icon-row">
        <Link to="/film" className="Film.js">
          <img className="film-button" src={film} alt="film" />
        </Link>
        <Link to="/tv" className="TV.js">
          <img className="tv-button" src={tv} alt="tv" />
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
);

export const Films = () => (
  <div className="table-content">
    <Film />
  </div>
);

export const TVseries = () => (
  <div className="table-content">
    <TV />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

---

When I run my application using 'npm start' the page loads, but only the banner is visible. If I click on the banner(which is also a Link), I get the page I want to load to begin with(Banner + Home component, wrapped in a mainpage div).

I was under the impression that since the path for Home is "/" it would load automatically on page load. What am I missing here?

Comment: What's your path after clicking this `Link`?

Comment: What does happen if you comment out from `<Link to="/">` to `</Link>` in App extends component?

Comment: Thank you both @k-wasilewski and Magofoco(can't tag both)!

I forgot that I changed the homepage in package.json to make it available in Github Pages. I got tunnel vision and didn't even notice that the path changed when I clicked on the banner.